# Shadow under fixed header upon scrolling

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am creating a website and I want shadow under my fixed header upon scrolling.
This means when the site loads there is no shadow under the header but when I scroll the page the shadow should appear below the header.
Here is my css code

EDIT : I am using reactjs for rendering the header

```
.nav-heading {
  background-color: $white;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  // margin-top: 1.25rem;
}
.nav-heading::after {
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use JQuery, that is a javascript lib.

First you need to install JQuery.
One easy way is by CDN.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then add your script like this.

```
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".nav-heading").css("box-shadow","here insert the value you want for the box-shadow")
  })
</script>
```

If you want to the shadow fade out after scrolling you can use:

```
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".nav-heading").css("box-shadow","here insert the value you want for the box-shadow").fadeOut( "slow" );
  })
</script>
```

You can access more about in:
https://code.jquery.com/

**Edit: How Using React.js**

You can create functions to deal with the state of scrolled or not.

```
   constructor() {
     super();
     this.state = {
        className: 'notShadow'
     }
   }

   handleScroll() { 
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 430) {
       this.setState({
         className: 'withShadow'
       })
     } 
   }
 
   componentDidMount() {
     window.onscroll = () => this.handleScroll()
   }
```

And then inside your header you can call the state as class.

```
<Nav className={this.state.className} />
```

If you don't know the number of pixels you can use:

```
console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop);
```

Comment: But how can i use inside react .

Comment: Sorry only after your edit I saw about React. I edited my answer